# Using "nameof" instead of passing the name as a string value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Following a MVC Core example such as below:

```
public ViewResult List() => View(repository.Orders.Where(t => t.Shipped == false));

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MarkShipped(int orderID)
{
    Order order = repository.Orders.FirstOrDefault(t => t.OrderID == orderID);
    if (order != null)
    {
        order.Shipped = true;
        repository.SaveOrder(order);
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
}
```

Noticed the last line says `return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));`  So my question is what's the difference if he has said return `RedirectToAction("List");` or maybe that's even wrong?

Comment: I guess in this instance `return RedirectToAction(nameof(List))` is the same with `return RedirectToAction("List")` see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Comment: Since `nameof(List)` references a variable, in case you're doing a refactoring, this will be updated along with the `List` variable - while a "magic" literal string "List" will not - that's just one big advantage

Comment: @marc_s oh refactoring as if I change the name of the VIEW from List.cshtml to something else in future?

Comment: Exactly - if you rename `List` to `MyList` - if you have `nameof(List)`, that will be refactored to `nameof(MyList)` and keep working - but if you have `RedirectToAction("List")`, that string literal **won't be** updated by the refactoring and thus point to a non-existing action now.....